# CSS Custom checkbox do not hide :after and :before elements

Tags: html, css, button, checkbox

I wrote this piece of CSS code to create own checkboxes:

```
input[type="checkbox"]{
  display: none;
}
.checkbox{
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 19px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.checkbox input[type="checkbox"] + label{
  left: 0%;
  top: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute; /*otherwise ,,left: x px;" isn't working*/
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 19px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 2px red;

  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
   transition: all .5s ease;
}

.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label{
   left: 50%;
   z-index: 1;
   background-color: blue;
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 2px green;
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before{
   content: "\2714";
   position: absolute;
   left: 8px;
   color: white;
}

.checkbox input[type="checkbox"] + label:before{
  content: "\2718";
  position: absolute;
  left: 8px;
  color: white;
}

.checkbox:before{
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  content: "Yes";
  color: white;
}

.checkbox:after{
  position: absolute;
  left: 35px;
  content: "No";
  color: white;
}
```

And I placed it on CSS Desk: [CSSDesk: Decorative checkboxes](http://cssdeck.com/labs/vqmzfhxc). Next, in my another codecast, I replaced default checkboxes which were used to disable buttons created by me: [CSS Desk: 3D Buttons](http://cssdeck.com/labs/ia00mvkt). Unfortunately, something wrong happened - in [3D Buttons (click to see codecast)](http://cssdeck.com/labs/ia00mvkt) checkbox does not hide :after/:before elements properly - for example when you have all buttons enable and on checkbox you see "No" content, still "s" from "Yes" is visible - I think something change font size but I don't know how to prove it - and how to fix it. Only change that I made in `.checkbox` div is that I add CSS `display: inline-block;` to display checkbox after buttons:

```
<div class="checkbox" style="display: inline-block;">
  <input id="disableInfo" type="checkbox">
  <label for="disableInfo"></label>
</div>disable info buttons
 <br/><br/><br/><br/>
```

I have no idea what happened. It would be great if anybody decides to help me - thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example your `font-family` is set to the default `serif`. In the second example, it's set to `sans-serif` by some styles included with the page. Either find out which of the styles are messing it up or set it manually to `serif`.

---

Anyway, AFAIK questions like "Here's a dump of my code. What have I done wrong?" don't really belong on SO.

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with my question, but your idea to change font-family works - thanks for help :)

Comment: Good question means isolating the problem and posting only the code relevant to it. That way even somebody else than the poster may profit from the answer in the future.